# Generate sourcemaps with requirejs without including sources?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, uglifyjs2

I'm using grunt and requirejs to build and compress our app for deployment. We want to create source maps that can be used for debugging client code remotely, without exposing our uncompressed dev code. In the requirejs options, I'm specifying for optimization:

```
options: {
    // ...,
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    // ...,
    uglify2: {
        mangle: {
            except: ['jQuery']
        },
        compress: {
            sequences: true,
            booleans: true,
            evaluate: true,
            conditionals: true,
            comparisons: true
        }
    },
    generateSourceMaps: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    // ...
}
```

This generates sourcemaps as expected, but they include the source files inside the maps, which increases file size significantly and exposes our original dev code. UglifyJS2 docs says it supports a sourceMapIncludeSources option which I've tried passing in an options object in the uglifyjs2 config, but it does not appear to be respected here. Is there a way to get requirejs to generate source maps without including the sources, or to get it to respect the options passed to uglify?